# anchor button to call server side method

Tags: c#, asp.net, architecture, postback, anchor

I want to call a server side method using an anchor button. I can't use `linkbutton` as I want to create an anchor button in the code-behind.

Here is a quick code sample:
I created a `div` in the front end and the id is "dv"

```
<div id ="dv" runat="server">
```

code behind:

```
 dv.InnerHtml =  "<a href=\"javascript:void(0);\" id=" + dxm.Id + " onclick=\"__doPostBack('" + dxm.Id + "', '');\" > </a>";
```

In this method i want to pass in the id by calling the button. When the button is clicked it will do a postback and send the id to this method.

```
protect void PopupBox(string id)
{
   //using the id get the data.
   //show modalpopup box
}
```

I dont want to use linkbutton. I used div as a example. I am using a treeview with inside this i will use node text to create a anchor button

```
node.text = "<a href=\"javascript:void(0);\" id=" + dxm.Id + " onclick=\"__doPostBack('" + dxm.Id + "', '');\" > </a>";
```

Answer (score 2):

In asp.net version 4 this 'hack' action of postback does not work because of the extra security checks that version 4 includes. The best way to do this using asp.net controls is to do a dynamic load of the controls. Here is some code that I have just checked and working.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // create the control dynamically
    LinkButton lbOneMore = new LinkButton();

    // the text and the commands
    lbOneMore.Text = "One more click";        
    lbOneMore.CommandArgument = "cArg";
    lbOneMore.CommandName = "CName";

    // the click handler
    lbOneMore.Click += new EventHandler(lbOneMore_Click);

    // and now add this button link to your div
    DivControl.Controls.Add(lbOneMore);
}

// here you come with the click, and the sender contains the commands
void lbOneMore_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtDebug.Text += "<br> Command: " + ((LinkButton)sender).CommandArgument;
}
```

On asp.net page :

```
<div runat="server" id="DivControl"></div>
<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="txtDebug" />
```

Comment: I dont want to use linkbutton. I used div as a example. I am using a treeview with inside this i will use node text to create a anchor button

Comment: @user929153 I can not understand you, or you me. In any way you can not make hack on post back with out first declare it (at least on asp.net 4) what you dont like in this solution ? is make what you ask. its create what you ask on code behind. !